# Property value does not change after calling function that should have changed it

Tags: javascript, closures

In the following JavaScript code, I use a closure to build an object. When I call `personA.addFriend()` a few times, call `personA.ListOfFriends()`, and then print the value of `personA.numOfFriends`, it still gives me 0 instead of 2.

Why does it not get the value 2?

```js
function person(name) {
    var name = name;
    var friends = [];
    var numOfFriends = 0;
    return {
        sayMyName: function() {
            return name;
        },
        sayHello: function() {
            return "hello" + " " + name;
        },
        addFriend:function(obj){
            numOfFriends += 1;
            friends.push(obj)
            return "you just became friend with " + obj.sayMyName();
        },
        listFriends: function(){
            return name + "! you have " + numOfFriends + " friends";
        },
        name: name,
        friends: friends,
        numOfFriends: numOfFriends   
    }
}
var personA = person("Ali")
var personB = person("Huda")
var personC = person("Mona")
personA.addFriend(personB); 
personA.addFriend(personC);
personA.listFriends();

console.log(personA.numOfFriends);
```

Comment: this code will surely throw error , the first return statement is not inside any function

Comment: Please post the first line of your code as well :-)

Comment: Sorry for that. I added the function name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you assign `numOfFriends` to the property with the same name, you will have two separate values, both living their own lives. When later the `numOfFriends` variable is incremented, the property will not change.

To fix this, you should not reference the variable in the methods, but the property. So do this:

```
this.numOfFriends+=1;
^^^^
```

And:

```
return name+"! you have "+this.numOfFriends+" friends";
                          ^^^^
```

Do the same with the other variable `name` that could suffer from the same problem (if you would have a method to change it).

Comment: Thanks a lot @trincot, you saved my life!

Comment: can you please upvote my question if you find it clear enough? . Thank you!